# Express.js Serving static file with virtual path - File Not Found

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In Express, I'm getting a 404 error when trying to access a static virtual path.

I've checked and double-checked. Everything seems in order, but it continues to generate the error.

The file I am trying to access is:

> /Users/terrymorse/PhpstormProjects/node-web-dev/chap06/notes/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css

My code:

```
app.use('/vendor/bootstrap',
    express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'bower_components', 'bootstrap', 'dist')));
```

I verified that `path.join()` produces this:

> /Users/terrymorse/PhpstormProjects/node-web-dev/chap06/notes/bower_components/bootstrap/dist

But when I try:

> http://localhost:3000/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css

I get a **Not Found 404** error. Any ideas?

Comment: Very weird, try to restart you local server, maybe it's started in another project and you forgot... :D

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Sadly,I tried a restart to no avail.

Comment: Fixed it by moving the 'app.use()' function earlier in the code. Not sure why, but I'll take the win.